# &nbsp; in PDF is shown as square

Tags: visualforce, pdf

I have this page

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" 
           sidebar="false" 
           standardStylesheets="false" 
           applyHtmlTag="false" 
           applyBodyTag="false" 
           docType="html-5.0" 
           cache="true"
           standardController="Controller..."
           extensions="Exctension ..." 
           renderAs="pdf">

<p class="font-normal"><strong>Text: </strong>**&nbsp;**</p>
<span class="input">**&nbsp;**<apex:outputText value="Text"/></span>
```

After I print the PDF, this "&nbsp ;" (non breaking space) is shown as a small square (looks like the border-lines of the "&nbsp ;" are dark)

The problem appears not always and only in Firefox (current version 43.0.3. appeared in older versions)

You had the same problem? Do you know where this come from?